# Suppress delete-non-virtual-dtor warning when using a protected non-virtual destructor

Tags: c++, g++

I have a pure abstract interface class, and a derived class which implements the interface.

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    void doStuff() override { }
};
```

My interface class **doesn't have a virtual destructor**.

Attempting to destruct a derived instance using a base class pointer is obviously therefore undefined behaviour

```
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Bar;
    f->doStuff();
    delete f;
}
```

Luckily my compiler is clever enough to catch this (with `-Werror`)

> ```
> main.cc:15:9: error: deleting object of abstract class type ‘Foo’ which has
>     non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor]
>  delete f;
>         ^
> ```

I can avoid this undefined behaviour by ensuring I don't attempt to delete using a base class pointer

```
int main()
{
    Bar* b = new Bar;
    b->doStuff();
    delete b;
}
```

Unfortunately it's not clever enough to pick up that this program is well formed, and spits out a similar error

> ```
> main.cc:15:9: error: deleting object of polymorphic class type ‘Bar’ which has 
>     non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour [-Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor]
>   delete b;
>      ^
> ```

Interestingly it says *might* cause undefined behaviour, not *will*

**Protected non-virtual destructor:**

In [one of Herb Sutter's Guru of the Week's](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) he gives the following advice:

> Guideline #4: A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual.

So lets make my destructor protected nonvirtual.

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
protected:
    ~Foo() = default;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    void doStuff() override { }
};
```

Now when I accidentally try to delete using a base class pointer I get another failure

```
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Bar;
    f->doStuff();
    delete f;
}
```

> ```
> main.cc:5:2: error: ‘Foo::~Foo()’ is protected
>   ~Foo() = default;
>   ^
> main.cc:17:9: error: within this context
>   delete f;
>          ^
> ```

Great, that gives me what I was looking for. Let's fix the code so I don't delete using a base class pointer

```
int main()
{
    Bar* b = new Bar;
    b->doStuff();
    delete b;
}
```

Unfortunately I get the same error as before

> ```
> main.cc:17:9: error: deleting object of polymorphic class type ‘Bar’ which has 
> non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour [-Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor]
>   delete b;
>          ^
> ```

**Question:**

How can I get the best of both worlds?

- Keep the `delete-non-virtual-dtor` error for when I forget to create a protected non-virtual destructor, and I try delete through a base-class pointer
- Suppress the warning when I use a protected non-virtual destructor, and I delete through a derived-class pointer

Super awesome bonus extra:

- Suppress the warning when I forget to use a protected non-virtual destructor, but I am correctly deleting through a derived-class pointer

Comment: Can you mark `Bar` as `final class` ?

Comment: The warnings seem to be compiler dependent. You may want to add the compiler tag(s) to the post.

Comment: @Jarod42 I could for some of the classes in my heirarchy, but unfortunately not for all

Comment: BTW, why not using virtual destructor ?

Comment: @Jarod42 no reason other than they weren't declared that way historically, and to now go back and change all of them (for an arguably unnecessary reason) is a lot of work

Comment: I don't have warning neither when using `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24cfadb3e750f366), but it might be wrong for `unique_ptr` :-(.

Comment: @Jarod42 whaaaaat? How does that work?! Very interesting! Confusing too!

Comment: @Jarod42 why do you say it might be wrong for `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Compiler may ignores (on purpose ) warnings in system header library.

Comment: @Jarod42 ah yes indeed, ok

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Bar> b = std::unique_ptr<Bar_Derived>();` should be invalid (as UB), but no errors/warning. (No problem with `shared_ptr` as the `Deleter` is also copied).

Comment: @SteveLorimer: I honestly don't think adding virtual destructors to the classes could possibly be more work than asking this question, reviewing and trying out all the suggested solutions, tinkering with compiler options and "fixing" some other code. Just add the virtual destructors and be done with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the problem is in **Bar** not in **Foo**.  If you were to have another class that inherits from Bar say Baz:

```
struct Baz : public Bar
{
  void doStuff() override { }
};
```

This could lead to undefined behavior such as the case

```
int main()
{
    Bar* bar_ptr = new Baz();
    bar_ptr->do_stuff();
    delete bar_ptr; // uh-oh! this is bad!
}
```

because the destructor in **Bar** is not virtual. So the solution is to mark Bar as final as has been suggested, or make the destructor in Bar virtual (since it's public) or make it protected in accordance with Herb's suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps a comment on if I *can't* make it `final`, that clearly implies I'm leaving open the option of a user subclassing it, which therefore *requires* the destructor be virtual. In any event, thank you - this has illustrated the missing part of the problem I hadn't grokked yet

Answer (score 8):

Marking the class `final` remove the warning.

```
struct Bar final : Foo
{
    void doStuff() override { }
};

int main()
{
    Bar* f = new Bar;
    f->doStuff();
    delete f;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/106be349618f63e7)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a general solution for my use-case

Answer (score 0):

If your `Bar` class is something you can't change, you can do the following:

```cpp
struct BarFinal final : Bar {};

int main()
{
    BarFinal * b = new BarFinal;
    b->doStuff();
    delete b;
}
```